# ¿Cómo hacer print de un aviso sin repetir miles de veces en un for?

Tags: python, bucle-for, yolo

Estoy usando Yolo para un proyecto de detección de objetos sobre videos.

Necesito hacer que al detectar un objeto mande un aviso, pero no consigo hacer que se mande una sola vez, ya que esta dentro de un ciclo `for`.

Tengo entendido que se puede poner una condición para que el `print` no se repita pero no tengo idea de como hacer

```
for detection in detections:
        if detection is not None:
            detection = rescale_boxes(detection, opt.img_size, RGBimg.shape[:2])
            for x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, cls_conf, cls_pred in detection:
                box_w = x2 - x1
                box_h = y2 - y1                       
                color = [int(c) for c in colors[int(cls_pred)]]
                print("Se detectó posible {}".format(classes[int(cls_pred)]))
                frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1 + box_h), (x2, y1), color, 5)
                cv2.putText(frame, classes[int(cls_pred)], (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, color, 5) # Nombre de la clase detectada
                cv2.putText(frame, str("%.2f" % float(conf)), (x2, y2 - box_h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,color, 5) # Certeza de prediccion de la clase
```

Comment: Yo lo haría con una variable fuera del bucle definida como false, luego, dentro del bucle, si se detecta lo que sea, pones la variable a true, por último, al finalizar el bucle, puedes hacer una condición tal que si la variable es true, muestras el print. Además, puedes crear otra variable para ir añadiendo las detecciones, y al finalizar el bucle, mostrar en un único print, el resultado final.

Comment: @track3r Voy a ir probando lo que me dijiste, creo que eso puede servir, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para manejar casos que se deben ejecutar sólo una vez dentro de un bucle repetitivo (`for` o `while`) se usa una variable lógica.

La variable lógica indica si ya se ejecutó la acción. Una vez ejecutada, la variable cambia de valor para impedir la repetición de la acción.

También puedes ocupar un entero cuando la condición implique contar repeticiones del bucle. En este caso, vas contando hasta llegar al valor deseado (ver ejemplos)

**Ejemplo**

Este código imprime una lista de número, poniendo el primero entre asteriscos:

```
impreso = False
for x in range(10):
    if not impreso:
        impreso = True
        print("*", x, "*")
    else:
        print(x)
```

produce

```
* 0 *
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Extensiones**

El método se puede extender a condiciones más complicadas. Por ejemplo, imprimir sólo después de encontrar el primer valor "3":

```
numero3 = 0
for x in range(10):
    if numero3:
        print(x)
    elif x == 3 and not numero3:
        print("Encontrado 3")
        numero3 += 1
```

En este caso tenemos usamos la cuenta de "3" encontrados como variable de control. De paso, también nos dice si es el primer "3" encontrado, en cuyo caso hay que imprimir un mensaje.

O cuando te piden imprimir sólo las tres primeras lineas mientras aplicas otros procesos al resto:

```
impresos = 0
for x in range(10):
    if impresos < 3:
        print(x)
        impresos += 1
```

Igual sirve para un `while`:

```
impresos = 0
while True:
    linea = archivo.readline()
    if impresos < 3:
        print(linea)
        impresos += 1
    ... otros procesos con la linea ...
```